# Format rows based on values in two cells in each row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I am trying to apply formatting conditionally:

> If in row 1, C = 0 and D = 0 highlight the entire row 1, then repeat for each row.

I have the following formula:

```
=(AND($C$1=0, $D$1=0))
```

but with this I have two issues:

- the formatting is applied just in row 1, and not subsequent rows
- only the column I am applying the conditional formatting to is highlighted, rather than a complete row.

How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slight variation on @JNevill's answer is to add provision to limit the CF to rows where C and D are not both blank (or your sheet may have a lot of highlighting if you do not limit the row range - and if you do limit the row range at some time in future it may not be sufficient). Blank cells trigger an `=0` condition.

So a CF formula such as:

```
=AND($C1=0,$D1=0,$C1<>"",$D1<>"")
```

and an Applies to range such as:

```
=$A:$Z
```

or further "east" to suit:

[image: SO260224013 example]

Answer (score 3):

You need to apply the condition to every column in every row that you want highlighted. Also your formula shouldn't have the Rows locked with the $ symbol. It should read: `=AND($C1=0, $D1=0)`

Comment: Removed the superfluous parentheses.